# Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have started developing a springboot REST API for crud operations and i was able to finish the data retrieving part , however having some troubles with POST request.

I have an Entity Called Job

```
@Entity
@Table(name="JOB")
public class Job {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="JOB_ID")
private Long jobId;

@Column(name="JOB_CODE")
private String jobCode;

@Column(name="JOB_DESCRIPTION")
private String jobDescription;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="job")
@JsonManagedReference(value="tasks")
private List<JobTask> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Please note that i have used @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotations to avoid the cycle references.

This is my child element JobTask`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="JOB_TASK")
public class JobTask {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="JOB_TASK_ID")
private Long jobTaskId;

private String taskDescription;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="JOB_ID")
@JsonBackReference(value="tasks")
private Job job;`
```

Then i tried a POST request to Create a Job with below JSON`

```
{
"jobCode": "QM",
"jobDescription": "Quaterly Maintenance",
"taskList": [
{
     "taskDescription": "Quarter Engine Asess"
 },
 {
      "taskDescription": "Quarter Break Asess"
 }
]`
}
```

However now i am getting below exception for POST requests`

Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.abc.entity.Job]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.abc.entity.JobTask)`

I did seach on this site and found some recommendations to use @JsonIdentityInfo
instead of @JsonManagedReference/ @JsonBackReference annotations. But i do not want to use @JsonIdentityInfo as it returns an Id values instead of the fully serialized object when i read the Data using GET requests.

Any help would be deeply appreciated

Thanks,
Keth

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use implements Serializable like that :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="JOB_TASK")
    public class JobTask implements Serializable {
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="JOB")
    public class Job implements Serializable {
    }
```

you find here the controler to add somethings look at this eg:

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/pays")
    public class PaysController {
        @Autowired
        IManagerPays iManagerPays;

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Pays addPays(@RequestBody Pays pays) {
            return iManagerPays.addPays( pays);
        }
    }

    @Service
    public class ManagerPays implements IManagerPays {
        @Autowired
        private RepositoryPays repositorypays;

        @Override
        public Pays addPays(Pays pays) {

            return repositorypays.save(pays);
        }
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="ctr_pays")
    public class Pays {
        @Id
          @GeneratedValue
        private Integer idPays;
        private String nomPays;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="pays")
        private List<Ville> villes;
        public Pays(){

        }
    //getter and setter
    }
```

this example work fine.

Comment: hi @Mohamed Elgarnaoui, thanks for the response. i tried this and no luck. By the way what is the theory behind having implement the Serializable interface and Jackson De-Serialize functionality